# Find a list which has substring using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Find a list which has substring and replace the substring using python3?

```
nested_list=[["abc","def","ghi"],["lkj","poi","mnb"],["ddcode","ddd","zzzv"]]
list=[]
for line in nested_list:
        if line[0] == 'code':  #find a substring
           line[0] == qtycode  # replace 
           list.append(line)

output -->"qtycode","ddd","zzzv" #print that list only
```

Comment: Hi @suba, may I suggest accepting the answer to the previous questions you posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303644/find-a-list-which-has-substring-using-python3 if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> nested_list=[["abc","def","ghi"],["lkj","poi","mnb"],["ddcode","ddd","zzzv"]]

>>> new_list = []

>>> for main_index, inner_list in enumerate(nested_list):
         for index, inner_element in enumerate(inner_list):
             if 'code' in inner_element:
                 inner_list[index] = 'qtycode'
                 if (not new_list) or nested_list.index(inner_list) == main_index:
                     new_list = inner_list
                 else:
                     new_list.append(inner_list)
```

It updates the value to `'qtycode'` if `'code'` is present.

---

**Output:**

```
>>> new_list

['qtycode', 'ddd', 'zzzv']
```

Comment: @suba Hope it resolve your issue. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it solved your question.

Comment: @suba Please check now and cofirm.